# Getting wrong teradata version using java.sql.Connection;

Tags: database, jdbc, teradata

I tried below code. My teradata version is 15.00.02.02,  but below code giving me the majorVersion as 2.

```
   Connection conn = getDBConnection(connInfoPropMap);
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
      int majorVersion = meta.getDatabaseMajorVersion();
      System.out.println("major Version: " + majorVersion);
```

Comment: File a bug report with Teradata. What do you expect us to do about this?

Comment: It was working few months back. but now it is not working.  Is it because of the driver ?

Comment: Just tried this, major version returned as 15. JDBC driver version: 13